# libGDX makes screen smaller [Ubuntu]

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, libgdx, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 OS, NetBeans IDE and the last version of libGDX. When I close the libGDX window or just stop compiling the program, my screen flickers one time and its resolution changes to 640x480, and it goes to the upper left corner (the rest of the screen is black).

It is really frustrating, because **xrandr** and **xrandr -s 0** don't do anything and I have to log out to fix this. It happens even if I use some basic code like

```
public class MyGame extends Game{ 
    public void create() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 600;
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        LwjglApplication app = new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: are you using the VirtualBox?

Comment: ok, and do you have proper graphics drivers installed? I'm pretty sure it is not problem of libgdx but the OS

Comment: @m.antkowicz Yep, other apps and libraries work fine.